# Smooth compactification of a torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $T$ be a non-split torus over a number field $k$, we have
$$T_{\bar{k}} := T \times_k \bar{k} \cong \mathbb{G}_m^r,$$
where $r$ is the dimension of $T$.

When $r=1$, I know that the smooth compactification of $T$ is $\mathbb{P}^1_{\bar{k}}$, and the set $\mathbb{P}^1_{\bar{k}} \setminus T_{\bar{k}}$ consists of two points. For a general $r$, does the set $\mathbb{P}^1_{\bar{k}} \setminus T_{\bar{k}}$ contain $2^r$ or $2r$ points, or some other integer?

Furthermore, if an algebraic group $G$ is the extension of an abelian variety $A$ by the torus $T$ above, do we have a bijection
$$G_{\bar{k}}^c \setminus G_{\bar{k}} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1_{\bar{k}} \setminus T_{\bar{k}}$$
where $G^c_{\bar{k}}$ is the smooth compactification of $G$? In other words, are the missing points on $G_{\bar{k}}$ fully accounted for by its torus part?

Comment: There is no such thing as the smooth compactification -- they aren't unique in higher dimensions. Can you be more precise about what you want?

Comment: @AlexYoucis I was looking at Lemma 2.2 of *Local-global principles for 1-motives* by Harari and Szamuely. I realised that they referred to *a smooth compactification* so you're right and perhaps my question doesn't make sense. Speaking of dimension, what is the dimension of the semi-abelian variety $G$? Is it $\mathrm{dim}(T) + \mathrm{dim}(A)$? I've searched the literature but couldn't get anything precise.

Comment: The complement is also not going to be finite dimensional in higher dimensions I think. Anyways, for the question you asked: dimension is additive in short exact sequences of group schemes. There are many ways to see this, but one is to use the fact that for

$$1\to G_1\to G_2\to G_3\to 1$$

since you are in characteristic 0, then $\dim(G_i)=\dim(\mathrm{Lie}(G_i))$ as your groups are all smooth. Without loss of generality we can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed. Then, the Lie algebra functor can easily be shown to be exact since $H^1(k[\varepsilon],G)=0$ is easily seen to be zero.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you so much this was very helpful, I'll just leave the question here so others can refer to what you've wrote in the comments.

Comment: There are many smooth compactifications. One particularly nice class is formed by **toric varieties**.